# Is there a perl "not in" operator?

Tags: perl

Suppose I have an array of numbers and I want to ensure that all of these fall within one of the set (x,y,z), I'm currently checking that the following evaluates to 0 :

```
scalar ( grep { $_ ne x && $_ ne y && $_ ne z } @arr )
```

Was just wondering if it'll not be easier if we had "IN" and "NOT IN" sql-like operators in perl too..

```
scalar ( grep { $_ NOT IN (x,y,z) } @arr )
```

Or is there one already?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A typical way to solve this is to use a hash:

```
my %set = map {$_ => 1} qw( x y z ); # add x, y and z to the hash as keys
                                     # each with a value of 1

my @not_in_set = grep {not $set{$_}} @arr;
```

Answer (score 22):

The libraries [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util) or [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) are very useful here for testing list membership where you don't care about the values itself, but simply existence. These are more efficient than `grep`, because they stop looping through the list as soon as a match is found, which can really speed things up with long lists. Moreover these modules are written in C/XS, which is faster than any pure-perl implementation.

```
use List::MoreUtils 'any';

my @list = qw(foo bar baz);

my $exists = any { $_ eq 'foo' } @list;
print 'foo ', ($exists ? 'is' : 'is not'), " a member of the list\n";

$exists = any { $_ eq 'blah' } @list;
print 'blah ', ($exists ? 'is' : 'is not'), " a member of the list\n";
```

(If you are restricted to only using modules that come with core Perl, you can use `first` in List::Util -- it first shipped with perl in 5.7.3.)

Comment: IMO this should be the chosen answer

Comment: And today, ever since perl v5.20, List::Util now contains 'any' as well.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Perl 5.10 or above, willing to use an experimental feature in perl 5.18 and up, and willing to overlook that the ***feature is planned to be deprecated in 5.38***, the Smart Match operator will do what you're looking for.

```
# if Perl 5.18 or higher; otherwise not needed
no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch';

my @filter = qw(X Y Z);
my $not_in_filter = scalar grep { ! ($_ ~~ @filter) } @array;
```

If Filter and/or @array are large, it may be slow, however, due to it being O(N^2).  In that case, you can still use smart matching, and just change your filter:

```
my %filter = map { $_ => 1 } qw(X Y Z);
my $not_in_filter = scalar grep { ! ($_ ~~ %filter) } @array;
```

See [Smart Matching in Detail](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) in `perldoc perlsyn` for more info.

Also, if you need to support versions of perl between 5.10 and 5.18, consider using the cpan module `experimental`. This does version checks and includes the 'no warnings' if it finds a Perl version that requires it.

```
use experimental 'smartmatch';
```

See: [https://search.cpan.org/~leont/experimental-0.016/lib/experimental.pm](https://search.cpan.org/%7Eleont/experimental-0.016/lib/experimental.pm)

Comment: Thanks @Robert, ~~ is something new to me !!

Comment: @trinity And unfortunately the smartmatch family of features was marked as experimental in perl 5.18.0, so you probably shouldn't start using it.

Comment: Does your first sentence mean it wasn't experimental in Perl 5.10, but got downgraded to experimental status in Perl 5.18?

Comment: Yeah. Not only was it downgraded to experimental in Perl 5.18, but they plan to deprecate it completely. https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2022/12/msg265180.html

Answer (score 4):

If there are less than a few million different things in the array, you could also use the
textbook method of set difference using a hash:

```
my %seen;
@seen{ @arr } = (); # Create a key for every distinct value in @arr
delete @seen{ qw(x y z) }; # And remove the ones for x, y, and z

if (keys %seen) {
    # There was something in @arr that's not x, y, or z
} else {
    # There wasn't
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
my $target = 'bar';
my @look_in = ('foo','baz','bar','etc');
if( $target ~~ @look_in) {
    print "target is in array ";
}
```

~~ is in array

```
my $target = 'bar';
my @look_in = ('foo','baz','bar','etc');
if( not $target ~~ @look_in) {
    print "target is not in array";
}
```

this is called smartmatch, some people recommend not to use them, but they work quite nice with list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Member;
my $target = 'bar';
my @look_in = ('foo','baz','bar','etc');

if( member($target, @look_in) + 1) {
 print "It's a member of the array\n";
}
```

That can do the trick